# use inetc plugin for nsis with electron builder

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I am currently working on an installer for app made in electron, during the installation process i need to make simple POST request to verify credentials. I found that there is this `inetc` plugin that can do it. However since i am using electron builder which comes with nsis i dont really know how to install that plugin within this environment.

So this is where i found the nsis source (i think):

`node_modules\app-builder-lib\templates`

[image: nsis-source]

and then this is what i already tried:

1. copy `Plugins` directory from inetc package to (screen above) nsis directory
2. copy all contents of inetc package to (screen above) nsis directory and run `build_msvc` file

at the end when i try to compile my app i always get error:

`Plugin not found, cannot call inetc::post`

How it is possible to install that plugin and use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was experimenting with Anders answer however without much luck, then by utilising some git issue tracker and try - error method i figured out how its done for nsis with electron builder setup.

so these are the steps you take:

1. download `inetc` plugin and unpack it, then open `Plugins` directory
   [image: step2]
2. open your `electron` project directory, open `build` directory
   [image: step1]
3. copy contents of `Plugins` directory from `intec` into your project `build` location
   [image: step3]

At this point you are good to go and you can use `inetc` functionality inside your `installer.nsh` file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about electron-builder but it looks like it stores its plug-ins in a folder called `nsis-resources`, it might be somewhere under `%localappdata%\electron-builder\cache` perhaps. You could also try searching for nsProcess.dll because that is one of the 3rd-party plug-ins it bundles.

If all else fails, you can add a custom directory:

```
!addplugindir /x86-unicode "c:\mynsisplugins\x86-unicode"
```

You must also remember to use the correct plug-in target (/x86-unicode vs /x86-ansi).

Comment: I upvoted because indeed above works for situation where electron builder is not the case, however if you have electron builder setup like myself, use my own answer as its working.

Comment: Using !addplugindir inside a *.nsh script worked well for me